# Suppose $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals and $b_n = a_n + a_{n+1}$.

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals and $b_n = a_n + a_{n+1}$. Prove that $(b_n)$ is also a Cauchy sequence. You will want to use a different $N$ for the same $ε$ in each case.  This is from "Tools of the Trade" by Paul Sally Jr., exercise $3.5.13$.

Comment: Hint: the triangle inequality will be useful

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, since $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence, there exist $N_{\varepsilon}$ such that $$m,n\ge N_{\varepsilon}\qquad\implies\qquad|a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon/2$$
Then 
\begin{align}
m,n\ge N_{\varepsilon}\qquad\implies\qquad|b_m-b_n|&=|a_{m+1}+a_{m}-a_{n+1}-a_{n+1}|\\
&\le|a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}|+|a_m-a_n|\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
&=\varepsilon
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

\begin{align*}
|b_n-b_m| & =|(a_n+a_{n+1})-(a_m+a_{m+1})|\\ 
& =|(a_n-a_{m})+(a_{n+1}-a_{m+1})|\\ 
& \leq |a_n-a_{m}|+|a_{n+1}-a_{m+1}| &&(\text{by triangle inequality})
\end{align*}
You are given that $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy: so For every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $K$ such that for all $m,n >K$, 
$$|a_n-a_{m}| \leq \epsilon.$$
Now use this to get bounds on $|b_n-b_m|$.